# Interpolate between three colors

Tags: colors, shader

I need to linearly interpolate between colors A and B so that at t=.1 the color is 0.5A + 0.5B. How can I achieve this?

I need to use this in a shader, so a conditional statement isn't an option, because branching can get quite slow. I need the solution in an expression-form.

Here's my solution, which is quite slow:

```
fixed3 color1= lerp(colorA, colorB, (1.0 - t) * .5 );
fixed3 borderColor= lerp(colorA, colorB, (1.0 - .1) * .5);
fixed3 color2= lerp(colorA, borderColor, t * 10.0 );

finalColor = lerp(color2, color1, saturate( (t - .1) * 100000.0) );
```

The last lerp is to insure that the interpolation value is either 0 or 1.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I will concentrate on the first line of your question: linear interpolation between two color values or color vectors.

You define an arbitrary point in time that marks the middle point of the interpolation:

```
tm = 0.1
```

For the calculation of the color vector **C(t)** you also need to define a starting time t1 or end time t2, or both:

```
t1 = t2 - 2*(t2-tm) = 2*tm - t2
t2 = t1 + 2*(tm-t1) = 2*tm - t1
```

To make the transition between color **A** to color **B**, you calculate the color components like this:

```
C = A + (B - A) * (t - t1) / (t2 - t1)
```

Comment: In my case t is normalized to [0..1]. How would the equations change? Do I have to set t1=0 or t2=1? I've tried to plot the equation, but it seems to be a straight line, instead of a broken one: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+0+%2B+%281+-+0%29+*+%28t+-+0%29+%2F+%28.2-+0%29%3B+from+0+to+1

Comment: I assumed a linear transition from color A to B with tm in the middle. However, you have a break in your interpolation. You didn't mention this in the question. The solution for the break point could be a function that gives zero for t<tm and 1 for t>=tm (e.g. F(t)=(abs(t-tm)/(t-tm)-1)/2 ). Then you can multiply it with the color and the break is there without branching: **C=F*color1+(F-1)*color2**. The last issue could be division by zero at t=tm.